# Calling new key word twice, both at declaration and in a method

Tags: java, collections

I am working on re factoring a code base. I want to know what exactly happens in the memory, when a container like Vector is instantiated twice both at declaration and in the method where it is being used.  The code is as follows.

```
Vector<String> rows = new Vector<String>();
```

In a method where its used,

```
rows = new Vector<String>();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code creates two separate `Vector` instances.

If you don't use the variable between those two lines, the first one is pointless.

Comment: It's probably worse then pointless, right?  Wouldn't this waste some memory?

Comment: Yes and no. You would allocate and waste memory, but the garbage collector would get rid of it again at some time.

Comment: @Sentry But this forces the GC to get called sooner, so you lose speed at the end of the day.

Comment: @Slaks.. Lets say I have not created the instance at declaration and created the instance inside the method call, every time the method is called, a new instance of the Vector will be created right?  If my functionality doesn't require a new instance(an empty vector), this will be an overhead right? or is this insignificant as GC takes care of old vectors?

Comment: @Cruncher Your point being? The comment of nhgrif was asking about memory, not time.

Comment: @Sentry I was just adding some value. It's time lost as a result of needless memory. Wasn't intending to be argumentative.

Comment: @Cruncher The OP was also asking specifically about memory and I didn't want to make it more complicated. You're right, of course, maybe I was just a bit too defensive ;)

Answer (score 6):

You end up creating 2 objects, but retaining only one in the end.

```
Vector<String> rows = new Vector<String>();
```

[image]

```
rows = new Vector<String>();
```

[image]

You can safely set it to `null` during declaration, then issue the second line only when you're about to use the rows variable for the first time.

Comment: Although object A will be gone shortly after `rows` is reassigned. It doesn't just live there forever, it'll be picked up by the GC.

Comment: @arshajii: Revised pic to depict GC.

Answer (score 0):

Two new `Vector` objects are allocated. The second one doesn't know or care that the first one was allocated.